# WiFi Password code keeps giving error on execution, says: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netsh'

Tags: python

```py
# first we will import the subprocess module
import subprocess

# now we will store the profiles data in "data" variable by 
# running the 1st cmd command using subprocess.check_output
data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')

# now we will store the profile by converting them to list
profiles = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in data if "All User Profile" in i]

# using for loop in python we are checking and printing the wifi 
# passwords if they are available using the 2nd cmd command
for i in profiles:
    # running the 2nd cmd command to check passwords
    results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', i, 
                        'key=clear']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    # storing passwords after converting them to list
    results = [b.split(":")[1][1:-1] for b in results if "Key Content" in b]
    # printing the profiles(wifi name) with their passwords using 
    # try and except method 
    try:
        print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, results[0]))
    except IndexError:
        print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, ""))
```

it keeps giving the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netsh'

is there any library i need to download or install? I am running it on my MacOS and Pycharm IDE

Comment: `netsh` is a Windows program afaik. Do you have in on your Mac?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I dont think it's available on my macbook

Comment: Then that's the problem. You're trying to have `subprocess` run a program that you don't have. You'd need to find a mac port of it, or look for a different program to defer work to.

Comment: You should find out the equivalent Mac command. Ask on [apple.se]

Comment: There may not be such a command. On MacOS, WiFi passwords are stored in the keychain.

Comment: If you are using windows pc then you have to import "os" module and command is "os.command" then you can use

Answer (score 0):

This script works only on windows.

```
subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show'])
```

You have to create a cross-platform script like this:

```
from sys import platform
if platform == "win32":  # Windows
    connect_wifi_windows()
elif platform == "linux":
    connect_wifi_linux()
else:
    raise OSError
```

Then you have to write functions: `connect_wifi_windows` and `connect_wifi_linux`

For linux systems, just try this and change the grep argument to find passwords:

```
os.popen('/sbin/iwconfig | grep ESSID').read()
```

It should be similar for macOS which is Unix based.